# Apache SVN Authorize to Active Directory Group

Tags: apache, svn, active-directory, ldap

I am working on setting up an Apache SVN system that will use our company's Active Directory to control access to the repositories. Note that I am not an IT guy, nor do I play one on TV.

IT gave me a read-only account so I can query the server. That seems to be working fine and I can query on the command line with ldapsearch as well as with Apache Directory Studio.

In our active directory, we have our users under something like

`OU=Users,OU=DIVISION,DC=INTRANET,DC=CORP`

with the username contained in the `sAMAccountName` attribute (for example - `srogers`). We then have a set of groups under `OU=Groups,OU=DIVISION,DC=INTRANET,DC=CORP`, and each group has a number of member attributes with the distinguished name.

Group - `CN=SoftwareEngineering,OU=Groups,OU=DIVISION,DC=INTRANET,DC=CORP`

member: `CN=SteveRogers,OU=Users,OU=DIVISION,DC=INTRANET,DC=CORP`

I am trying to get Apache SVN to authorize to the SoftwareEngineering group, but I cannot make it work. Here is my configuration file.

```
<Location /svn>
  DAV svn
  SVNParentPath /var/www/svn
  SVNListParentPath On

  # Use LDAP auth against an active directory
  AuthName "Enter your username and password"
  AuthType Basic
  AuthBasicProvider ldap
  AuthLDAPBindDN "CN=readonlyuser,OU=Services,OU=DIVISION,DC=INTRANET,DC=CORP"
  AuthLDAPBindPassword <password>
  AuthLDAPGroupAttributeIsDN on
# ----------------- Authorizes any user
#  AuthLDAPURL "ldap://divdc.intranet.corp:389/OU=DIVISION,DC=INTRANET,DC=CORP?sAMAccountName?sub?(ObjectClass=*)"
#  Require valid-user


  AuthLDAPURL "ldap://divdc.intranet.corp:389/OU=DIVISION,DC=INTRANET,DC=CORP?sAMAccountName"
  Require ldap-group CN=SoftwareEngineering,OU=Groups,OU=DIVISION,DC=INTRANET,DC=CORP

</Location>
```

I try to simulate this with LDAP search and if I cut and paste the URL from the conf file, I get this...

`# ldapsearch -x -D cn=readonlyuser,dc=INTRANET,dc=CORP -W -H ldap://divdc.intranet.corp:389/OU=DIVISION,DC=INTRANET,DC=CORP?sAMAccountName
Could not parse LDAP URI(s)=ldap://dlsdc1.spa-elec.corp:389/OU=DLS,DC=SPA-ELEC,DC=CORP?sAMAccountName (3)`

I also tried with `sAMAccountName=srogers` and without the sAMAccountName part at all, with the same result.

Any ideas on what the magical incantation is to make this work? I've been all over and can't seem to get the **Require ldap-group** working.

OS = Ubuntu 16.04

Apache = 2.4.18

Comment: What does the apache log say?

Comment: [authz_core:error] [pid 5857:tid 140272191526656] [client 192.168.59.1:51651] AH01631: user srogers: authorization failure for "/svn/"

Comment: See http://serverfault.com/questions/437434/apache-httpd-ldap-integration for ideas and hints

Comment: There is VisualSVN Server and it handles this out of the box without any extra configuration. It has to be installed on Windows.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Require ldap-group` does not work with Subversion. Lazy Badger's link has details.

I fixed by installation by deleting the `Require ldap-group`, uncommenting the Require valid-user line, and fixing the AuthLDAPURL to add the appropriate LDAP filter.

The configuration now looks like this.

```
<Location /svn>
  DAV svn
  SVNParentPath /var/www/svn
  SVNListParentPath On

  # Use LDAP auth against an active directory
  AuthName "Enter your username and password"
  AuthType Basic
  AuthBasicProvider ldap
  AuthLDAPBindDN "CN=readonlyuser,OU=Services,OU=DIVISION,DC=INTRANET,DC=CORP"
  AuthLDAPBindPassword <password>
  AuthLDAPGroupAttributeIsDN on
  AuthLDAPURL "ldap://divdc.intranet.corp:389/OU=DIVISION,DC=INTRANET,DC=CORP?sAMAccountName?sub?(&(ObjectClass=*)(memberOf=CN=SoftwareEngineering,OU=Groups,OU=DIVISION,DC=INTRANET,DC=CORP))"
  Require valid-user
</Location>
```

This users in the filter group can connect, and users that are not in the filter group are denied.

I will ask how to give someone read-only permission through LDAP in another question.

Comment: I don't see that you specified a group anywhere. You don't specifically state that you no longer require that either. Just noting this here. Seems to me that you are allowing any user access as long as they are in your AD, hope thats what you wanted.